# How can I fix an Apache redirect loop

Tags: apache, wordpress, redirects, url-rewriting

I have a strange Apache/WordPress redirect loop that I can't seem to figure out.

Here is the relevant logs and other info: http://pastebin.com/E1afW2vw

It seems that the page request gets made, and it tries to redirect to the proper directory based on the Alias given in the httpd.conf file. But when it tries to replace back the given URL, it fails to recognize that the directory is an alias and doubles up the base directory (/blog/blog/).

Any ideas what might be causing this? And how to fix it?

Also... the .htaccess file is located in the root of the /wp directory that is aliased to /blog

Comment: You have already asked this question before, right? .. or maybe it is my imagination .. as I have definitely seen something like that already.

Comment: Yes, but in a different section of StackExchange.  I voted to delete the other one since this seems to be a better place for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you final rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

should be

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Since you're already in the `/blog/` directory there's no need to add that to the path.

Your first request is not matching any rewrite rules and is falling through to the default `DirectoryIndex`.

In the second request you are matching `2011/06/suits/` which gets rewritten to `/blog/index.php` but since you're already in the blog directory it adds the extra `/blog` and then re-runs through the rules. It re-strips-out the first `/blog` but then because your first rule doesn't match, it matches on the last rule repeating the process.

Comment: This works, but the only issue is that the rewrite rules were created by WordPress, and I'm worried that the client will click the "Update Permalinks" button, reverting to the original rewrite rules, and break the site.  Is there any other way around this issue besides editing the rewrite rules?

Comment: I haven't work with Wordpress enough to say how it handles the generation or why it generated what it did. My guess is that it has to do with the alias and what you told Wordpress it's path was. One option though is to change the permissions on the .htaccess file so that Wordpress wouldn't be allowed to change it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the permissions route if it becomes a problem.